# Sort ranges from 2 columns repeatedly in vba

Tags: excel, vba

With below code I could sort data (marked with blue background) from 2 columns based on "B" column. Similarly I want to repeat the same for each blue block. I've highlighted cells manually just for illustration. Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub SortRanges()
Dim firstcell As String
With Columns("B")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
    firstcell = ActiveCell.Row

End With

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Clear

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B" & firstcell & ":B" & firstcell + 5), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A" & firstcell & ":B" & firstcell + 5)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a loop down your column and, as it looks like everything is blocks of 5, do something like:

```
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i = 1 to lr 
    if cells(i,1).interior.color = Blue Then `FIX THIS TO MATCH THE BLUE YOU WANT
        Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+5,2)).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i+5,2)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        i=i+5
    End if
next i
```

---

I may have not understood the part about your highlighting... if that blue is the "highlight" then you can modify the above such that:

```
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i = 1 to lr 
    if not isempty(cells(i,2)) Then
        Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+5,2)).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i+5,2)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        i=i+5
    End if
next i
```

---

One more thing... if you can just run 2 sorts in sequence, second should be your final sort, like:

```
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i = 1 to lr 
    if not isempty(cells(i,2)) Then
        Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+5,2)).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+5,1)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i+5,2)).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i+5,2)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        i=i+5
    End if
next i
```

Comment: Working awesome! 2nd is the code that I was looking for. Didn't get the 3rd code.

Comment: @Experimenter The third code is just ensuring that you've sorted column A before you sort column B, to ensure X, Y, Z are in that order.  Wasn't positive how all of the data showed up, so threw that in there as a just in case to explain that those sorts can be run in series

Comment: @JohnyL in this scenario, you may have the first cell that isn't blank in, say, i=3 (we start i at 1).  Once you find the first instance, 5 cells will be grouped together; before we leave i=3 and move onto `Next i`, we need to increase i by 5 so the next i in the loop is i = (3+5+1) 9.  Using the step, you will go from i = 1 to i = 6 to i = 11, which may or may not catch your first instance (in the case of i = 3 being the first case, it would be missed completely).

Comment: @JohnyL If you were to use `i = 3 to lr step 5` that would be correct if you guaranteed that this occurs every 5 cells, which may or may not be the case.  In the provided data, where the last group of locations has only 4 data points (not grouped), you *might* skip some data sets if that occurs in the middle of your full data set.

Comment: Aha, got it... The number of rows between block is inconsistent.